# What's the difference in the quality of time evolution of MD vs QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics, applied-physics

In my research group, we're using molecular dynamics to estimate time evolution of molecules. Of course, the analogous calculations are unobtainable using time dependent Schrödinger equation using our computers and methods. It makes me wonder: «Is there is a theoretical justification why molecular dynamics provides something that would even vaguely resemble the answer that we would calculate using quantum mechanics?»

We get the forces using so-called ab-initio methods. I am mainly interested in understanding the degree of appropriateness of applying Newton second law to do time evolution of the nuclei. Equations would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT: This is not a question about Born-Oppenheimer approximation. You can ignore the impact of BOA if it helps.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation

Comment: Thanks. I've specified that I'm mainly interested in the time evolution.

Comment: It might be worth to ask this question on [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget to mark your posts as cross-posted, tho.

Comment: Are you using purely classical MD or mixed quantum-classical MD?